Freeswitch mask and unmask commands doesnt work when recording is started by lua script
I am trying to mask and unmask the call recordings which is being recorded automatically through some lua scrip using the command record_session. the lua script execut this command when the call is answered.
here is the lua script.
package.cpath ="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/?.so;" .. package.cpath
package.path = "/usr/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;" .. package.path

local callType = session:getVariable("sip_h_X-CallType")
local record_path = session:getVariable("record_path")
local uuid = session:getVariable("uuid")
local ext = session:getVariable("record_ext")
local customer_leg_uuid = ''
local api = freeswitch.API();

-- can be consult, OUT, MONITOR, PROGRESSIVE, 

local function fileExists(file)
    local f = io.open(record_path .. '/' .. file, 'r')
    if f == nil then
            -- freeswitch.consoleLog("ERROR", "set_recording_name.lua FILE NOT FOUND: " .. file)
            return false;
    end
    io.close(f);
    -- freeswitch.consoleLog("ERROR", "set_recording_name.lua FILE WAS FOUND: " .. file)
    return true;
end

local destination = tostring(session:getVariable("destination_number"))
-- freeswitch.consoleLog("NOTICE", " \n set_recording_name.lua DESTINATION \n " .. destination)


if (callType == "CONSULT") then
    freeswitch.consoleLog("NOTICE", " \n set_recording_name.lua RECORDING CONSULT CALL \n")
    session:execute("stop_record_session","all")
    if (string.match(tostring(destination), "99887766")) then
        return
    end   return
elseif (callType == "MONITOR") then -- no recording enabled here
    return
    -- callType == "PROGRESSIVE" or 
elseif (callType == "OUT") then -- for manual outbound use the preset other leg uuid i.e. customer leg uuid

    customer_leg_uuid = session:getVariable("customer_leg_uuid")
    freeswitch.consoleLog("NOTICE", " \n set_recording_name.lua UUID \n " .. uuid)
    freeswitch.consoleLog("NOTICE", " \n set_recording_name.lua CUSTOMER \n" .. customer_leg_uuid)
    if (uuid ~= customer_leg_uuid) then
        freeswitch.consoleLog("NOTICE", " \n set_recording_name.lua RECORDING MANUAL OUTBOUND CALL \n")
        session:setVariable("recording_command" , "nolocal:execute_on_answer=record_session " .. record_path .. "/" .. customer_leg_uuid .. "." .. ext)
        session:setVariable("recording_filename" , customer_leg_uuid .. "." .. ext)
        return
    end
    session:execute("stop_record_session","all")
    local res = api:executeString("bgapi uuid_broadcast " .. uuid .. " stop_record_session::all")
    uuid = customer_leg_uuid
end

local filename = uuid
-- inbound ivr case
freeswitch.consoleLog("NOTICE", "\n set_recording_name.lua RECORDING INBOUND CALL \n")
local count = 0
while (fileExists(filename .. '.' .. ext)) do
    count = count + 1
    filename = uuid .. '_' .. count
end

local suffix = '_' .. count
if (count == 0) then
    suffix = ''
end

filename = uuid .. suffix.. "." .. ext
session:setVariable("recording_filename" , filename)
session:setVariable("recording_command" , "nolocal:execute_on_answer=record_session " .. record_path .. "/" .. filename)


when the recording is started then I use the the below commands to mask and unmask the ongoing recording.
uuid_broadcast 6ce5c548f60e413ba70d6149a4883096 record_session_mask::${record_path}/${recording_filename}
uuid_broadcast 6ce5c548f60e413ba70d6149a4883096 record_session_unmask::${record_path}/${recording_filename}

the recording path and recording_filename are being retrieved from the session variable.
so the problem is that when I listen to the recording it doesn't get masked or unmasked.
PS: If I start the recording using the same command record_session and then run the above masking and unmasking commands, the recording gets masked.
So my question is what am I doing wrong here in the file or the commands that the call recorded by the Lua script doesn't get masked/unmasked
Any help will be appreciated
thanks
